# Push a view from a TabBarController programmatically created

Tags: uitableview, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I have created a tab bar controller as follows:

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

NSMutableArray *tabsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//tab1: dive info
LogsDetailDive *logsDetailDive = [[LogsDetailDive alloc] initWithNibName:@"LogsDetailDive" bundle:nil];
[logsDetailDive initWithLogSelected:logSelected:siteSelected];
logsDetailDive.title = @"Info";
logsDetailDive.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"/images/logs.png"];
[tabsArray addObject:logsDetailDive];

//tab2: deco info
...

//tab3: equipment info
...

//tab3: computer info
...

tabBarController.viewControllers = tabsArray;

[logsDetailDive release];

[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

This tab controller is pushed from a previous table view into the navigation controller.
What I'm trying to get now is to show another view pushed from a tableview in LogsDetailDive, but I really cannot understand what I am missing, since it doesn't work.
Can you suggest something?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[UITabBarController reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Because the UITabBarController class inherits from the UIViewController class, tab bar controllers have their own view that is accessible through the view property. When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller.

So the bottom line, this should not be done, and will cause some problems. If you need a tabbar layout you should instead use a toolbar.